# LIMIT в выборке случайных записей

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос вида:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM my_table JOIN ( SELECT CEIL(RAND() * ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table )) AS randomID ) AS random_table ON random_table.randomID=my_table.ID");
```

Он выбирает только одну запись (как и надо случайную), а LIMIT 10 нужный мне, нигде не работает, куда бы я его в этот запрос не вставлял. Запрос неправильного вида что-ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пардон, но если вы работаете только с одной таблицей, то зачем так усложнять? Может сделать проще, если ключ **id** у вас уникальный:

```
SELECT 
    `name` 
FROM 
    `my_table` 
WHERE `entry_id` >= (
        SELECT FLOOR( MAX(`entry_id`) * RAND() ) FROM `my_table`
    ) 
ORDER BY `entry_id` LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: А вот интересно. Тот вид запроса я нарыл в интернете, перечитав не одну статью. Очень понравился. Он(запрос) очень шустрый, правильный и т.д... А как измерить скорость выполнения запроса? Хочу поэкспериментировать.

Comment: Например, в phpMyAdmin показывается время выполнения запроса. Только сделайте его пару раз, чтоб вывести какую-то среднюю величину.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT first(name) FROM my_table JOIN ( SELECT CEIL(RAND() * ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table )) AS randomID ) AS random_table ON random_table.randomID=my_table.ID");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM my_table JOIN ( SELECT CEIL(RAND() * ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table )) AS randomID ) AS random_table ON random_table.randomID=my_table.ID") ORDER BY name LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: __Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ...__
__ORDER BY name LIMIT 1__ находится за пределами __mysql_query();__